# ReactJS directory structure for code sharing between server and client and between different clients

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I´m building an extensive react application using the `create-react-app` tool.

My application will have 3 different clients (an Admin panel, an Studio panel and an Analytics panel), 3 different react projects - `admin`, `studio` and `analytics` and 3 different git repositories, and 3 different teams working together.

These applications will be called by a single server that has all my database logic and my GraphQL Server (yes, I'm using relay) to allow access from clients.

We will have two classes of common code:

a) Shared between clients: UX stuff, like buttons, labels and themes are going to be shared between clients (all UX stull are React components)

B) Shared between clients and server: Schema, validators and other generic code are going to be shared between server and clients.

My first directory structure would be:

```
project
|
|-client
|   |---- admin
|   |       |---- src
|   |              |-------- <Admin code here>
|   |---- studio
|   |       |---- src
|   |              |-------- <Studio code here>
|   |---- analytics
|   |       |---- src
|   |              |-------- <Analytics code here>
|   |---- ux
|          |---- src
|                 |-------- <UX code here>
|   
|-server
|   |-------<Server code here: routes, GraphQL, etc.>
|   
|-common
|   |----- <Common code here (metadata schemas, validators, etc.)>
```

Altough nice, this does not work with React, as create-react-app cannot include in build bundle code outside src, so it will not allow me to include `ux` in the client packages nor common code in `common`. Also, in a build case, only code inside `src` are going to be ES6 interpreted, so even if I include external code I cannot compile the final bundle.

I don´t want to keep building links and copies around, so what would be solution for the above use case?

How to organize folders in a way that I can share the `ux` code between clients and common code in `common`between server and clients?

The solution must consider I´m using ES6 in all modules and that I need to build final bundles for every client at the end (`npm run build` from `create-react-app`)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you split all the client code into different react applications and handle this modules by using `nginx` or `apache` virtual host. The above thing won't work according to code management purpose. So make react app for `admin-panel`, `studio`, `analytics` and `ux` it will be easy for you to manage every modules.